# Why is my support vector machine model not working in R?

Tags: r, svm, predictive-models

I am using a Support Vector Machine model to predict the direction of a stock price given some independent variables. Here is part of my dataset:

```
post_eco  eco_ant     sd_eco      ant_cl1      sd_cl1
 Up         0        0.000000    -0.03      0.00948683
 Up         0        0.000000     0.04      0.01663330
 Down       0        0.000000    -0.04      0.02110818
 Down       0        0.000000    -0.11      0.03977715
 Down       0        0.000000    -0.19      0.06783149
 Down       5        2.041241    -0.19      0.08256983
```

I want to predict the direction using the variables listed.

```
post_eco: shows the direction the stock price is going to take in the next ten minutes: 'Up' or 'Down'.

eco_ant: tells me by how much has the stock price moved in the last 10 minutes.

sd_eco: tells me the standard deviation of the stock price in the last 10 minutes.

ant_cl1: tells me by how much has the oil price moved in the last 10 minutes.

sd_cl1: tells me the standard deviation of the oil price in the last 10 minutes.
```

I use the function:

```
svmfit=svm(post_eco~., data=train ,kernel ="radial",cost=0.0625,gamma=0.0625)
```

to apply the support vector machine and predict the relationship. The problem is that I get a 'Down' for every predicted observation (which does not make sense).

Comment: Are you tuning your hyperparameters? How?

Comment: What is the proportion of down in the full dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a linear kernel instead, or trying different values of the gamma parameter? Sometimes with RBF kernels a gamma parameter that is too large or small will lead to degeneracy.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the tuning, have you looked at the distribution of your outcome? Sometime there is a huge class-unbalance e.g. only two observations have 'Up' value and 10K observations have 'Down' value. In that case, there are several approaches suggested in the literature as remedies for class-unbalance.

Another suggestion would be scaling (in case the default is not scale = TRUE). Since margin computations and all depend on distances, magnitude of variables can hugely impact the model fit.